# How to make a HTML5 Geolocation object in python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, geolocation

I'm testing for some software analytics and I need to send GET requests with geolocation object with variable timestamps and locations. The site uses HTML5 navigator.getcurrent.location().

I can use random module to randomise locations & timestamps. However, the JSON object creation part is troubling me as the structure in documentation has null values and python dictionary doesn't accept it.

So, could you show me how to Just create an HTML5 Geolocation object in python which is ready to be sent via GET request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using eval to parse your JSON because you said python doesn't accept the null keyword. Using eval on JSON is asking for trouble in any language. Python has a built in JSON parser. Use it!

```
import json
# put GET response in location_json_string
location_dict = json.loads(location_json_string)
```

To encode:

```
# Put your data in data_dictionary
request_json = json.dumps(data_dictionary)
# send GET request appending request_json to the URL
```

Comment: Could you show what `location_json_strings` & `data_dictionary` would be for HTML5 Geolocation object as well ?